# C# WriteLine Works, Write fails - wacky bug?

Tags: c#, string, methods

So line #59 has what i can only describe as a wackadoodle error (if i'm understanding my code correctly that is) which is that if you leave the return line with `Console.ReadLine()` the file will run, if you change it to `Console.Read()`), the file will produce errors when running. The odd thing is that it shouldn't run because I don't call the functions or do the actual console.writes, etc. So i was hoping someone out there could help me to understand this and either confirm that i am correct in thinking i've got some wacky code OR that my understanding of how the code runs is incorrect.

Code that produces the error:

```
public string GetStr(String StrVar)//note - using strings here
{ 
  Console.Write(StrVar);return Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim(); 
}
```

If the line `return Console.ReadLine()` is changed to `return Console.Read()`, the file errors - but the file should really run regardless as i don't actually call anything - it seems like the string vars are somehow self-writing to the console if i understand what is happening.

Full Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace a015_mealCalculator
{
    class Program
    {
        public void Play()
        {
            //DisplayChek("DisplayChek!");

            do //do while loop
            {
                DisplayStr(">>>-- Meal Calculator v1.3 --<<< \n\n\n");//Welcome

                //ask info
                String fName = GetStr("Enter your FIRST NAME here: ");
                String lName = GetStr("Enter your LAST NAME here: ");
                String rName = GetStr("Enter the NAME of the RESTURANT you are dinning at here: ");
                String wholeName = fName + " " + lName;
                double mealCost = GetDouble("How much was your meal " + fName + "?");
                String mealGreeting = "\n" + wholeName + ", your meal at " + rName + " was:";    
                //process math
                double tax = mealCost / 8;
                double tip = mealCost % 18;
                double totalCost = mealCost + tip + tax;

                tax = Math.Round(tax, 2);//trim decimals
                tip = Math.Round(tip, 2);//trim decimals
                totalCost = Math.Round(totalCost, 2);    

                //Announce results
                Console.WriteLine("\nMeal: " + mealCost);
                Console.WriteLine(mealGreeting);
                Console.WriteLine("Meal: $" + mealCost);
                Console.WriteLine("Tax: $" + tax);
                Console.WriteLine("Tip: $" + tip);
                Console.WriteLine("Total: $" + totalCost);

            } while (PlayAgain());

            DisplayStr("Enjoy Your Meal!"); //Salutation
        }

        //MaxBox
        public void DisplayChek(String StringNameIs)
        { Console.WriteLine("I am in " + StringNameIs); }//Where are we?

        public void DisplayStr(String StrTxt)
        { Console.WriteLine(StrTxt); }

        public void DisplayRs()
        { Console.Write("\n\n"); }

        public string GetStr(String StrVar)//note - using strings here
        { Console.Write(StrVar);return Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim(); }

        public double GetDouble(String doubleRequest)// We take in a STRING but we return a DOUBLE
        {
            Console.WriteLine(doubleRequest + ": "); // HERE we use the STRING to ask for the DOULBE
            return double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //HERE we RETURN the DOUBLE asked for!
        }

        public Boolean PlayAgain()
        {
            Console.Write("\n\nDo you want to play again? (y)es or (n)o: ");
            String command = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            if (command == "y" || command == "yes") return true;
            return false;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program MealCalculator = new Program();
            MealCalculator.Play();

            //Play keeps file open
            //Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What file you are talking about?

Comment: I posted all of the code to the file I am referring to above (namespace a015_mealCalculator), as well as also posting the singular method/function that produces the super wackiness as I am understanding it which i believe happens on line #59.

Comment: Side note: this `double tip = mealCost % 18;` is *not* going to do what you mean. `%` is not a percent, it's a modulo.

Comment: Instead of "wackiness" please state what *error* you get when doing *what*.

Comment: "the string vars are somehow self-writing to the console" — no, they are not. There isn't *anything* “somehow” happening automagically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of both methods: [`Console.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the character code of the next character read from the console stream as an integer, whilst [`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a line as a string. [`double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) accepts a string parameter, so in the first case there is a type mismatch.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative answer. I thought that Read just read what was entered and returned and readline retuned the whole line including the line break. Thank you.

Comment: I do actually READ the documentation - I'm dyslexic so it's easy to miss things or become confused.

Answer (score 3):

Console.Read() returns an integer, ReadLine() returns a string.

The ReadLine method, or the KeyAvailable property and ReadKey method are preferable to using the Read method.

Comment: I did not know that, this was a very educational exercise for me - thank you.

Comment: I think i'm only allowed to check one answer or I'd check everyone. I thought that BartoszKP's was the very best answer but all the answers were uber helpful and very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This will not compile as Console.Read() returns an int.  You cannot perform .ToLower() on an int.

Comment: WOW. That is completely mind-blowing to me. Thank you very much.